# Importing OpenCV with python 2.7 in Virtualenv and PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv, pycharm

I am struggling with installing opencv for python 2.7.11 on OSX for almost three days now.

After some failures, I accomplished a first success by following the instructions [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/). So my basic setup is python 2.7.11 running from  `~/.virtualenvs/cv_env/bin/python` and I have a `cv2.so` located in `~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

So good so far. Using `source ~/.virtualenvs/cv_env/bin/activate`, I can activate the virtualenv and than use `import cv2`. For some reasons, this does not work always. From time to time, I have to deactivate first and than reactivate (any guesses?).

Next, I wanted to use opencv in PyCharm. Under "preferences - Project interpreter", I selected the virtualenv interpreter and this is also working. I can import other moduals like numpy and pandas (previously installed into the vortualenv using `pip`). But for some reasons, I am not able to import opencv (`import cv2`). It always gives me

`ImportError: No module named cv2`

So my question is, why I am able to import opencv in terminal (at least sometimes) but not in PyCharm. Any ideas are welcomed.

Best,
Fabian

Comment: Your `cv2.so` located in a different directory. And you activating from another directory. I mean `cv_env` and `cv`.

Comment: Hey Rahul, thanks for pointing that out. Quite a simple mistake but very helpful, problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cv2.so` located in a different directory. And you activating from another directory. I mean `cv_env` and `cv`.